# How to render in vueJS template while looping when receiving dynamic formats

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having a table in vue template like below,

```
<table class="table vmiddle no-padding hover table-striped" id="match-expressions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Attribute Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Expression</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Value</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template v-if="subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']">
            <tr v-for="(match_expressions,id) in subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']" :key="id">
                <td>{{match_expressions['attribute_name']}}</td>
                <td>{{match_expressions['operator']}}</td>
                <td>{{match_expressions['values']}}</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <tr>
                <td class="data-not-available" colspan="3">No Data</td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am looping subtypes['filter']['match_expressions'], which  will be like this,

```
[{ "attribute_name": "xyz", "operator": "In", "values": [ "SF100" ] }]
```

But sometimes, the subtypes['filter']['match_expressions'] will be come in below format,

```
{ "attribute_name": "xyz", "operator": "In", "values": [ "SF100" ] }
```

If it comes in object, v-for in template is not working. displaying like,

```
function values () { [nativeCode]}
```

Dont know how to avoid this. Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to VueJS.

Comment: You mean `subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']` can either be an array or object?

Comment: yeah, exactly @palaѕн

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update template like this in that case:

```
<template v-if="subtypes['filter']['match_expressions'] && Array.isArray(subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']">
  <tr v-for="(match_expressions,id) in subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']" :key="id">
    <td>{{match_expressions['attribute_name']}}</td>
    <td>{{match_expressions['operator']}}</td>
    <td>{{match_expressions['values']}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
<template v-else-if="subtypes['filter']['match_expressions'] && (typeof subtypes['filter']['match_expressions'] === 'object')">
  <tr>
    <td>{{subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']['attribute_name']}}</td>
    <td>{{subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']['operator']}}</td>
    <td>{{subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']['values']}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-not-available" colspan="3">No Data</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Here,

```
subtypes['filter']['match_expressions']
```

we are simply checking if the above expression is an array using `Array.isArray()`. I yes, then we use the `v-for` loop. If it is an object, then we do not need to loop, we can simply display the single object properties.

Comment: @palaSH Thank you so much. Will tryt this method. Hope this will work. But, if it is multiple objects like { "attribute_name": "xyz", "operator": "In", "values": [ "SF100" ] },{ "attribute_name": "abc", "operator": "In", "values": [ "SF120" ] }, how to loop this?

Comment: That is not a valid syntax as objects have to be in array like `var a =[{}, {}]` but if you run `var a = {},{}` in console you will get error immediately. I hope that make sense.

Comment: yeah got it. sorry.